# Block elements within site WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser, block

I have created a WebBrowser object and would like to know how to block specific elements of a page such as a flash object. I presume I would need to check for an offending URL and cancel the navigation to that element.

Comment: Please don't add things like "C#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I'd do something like this to disable the Flash elements

```
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    HtmlElementCollection hec = wb.Document.All;

    foreach (HtmlElement element in hec)
    {
        if (element.TagName == "OBJECT")
        {
            element.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the [`WebBrowser.Document.HtmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx) property to strip out any object tags responsible for displaying flash.